# Building protobuf using absolute path path python

Tags: python, path, protocol-buffers

I have protobuf definition in a folder like:

_ protocol
__ A
___ v1
____ a.proto
__ B
___ v1
____ b.proto
__ C
___ v1
____ c.proto

I want to built them and keep the same structure.

To do so I use this command : `protoc -I=./my_folder/data/my_subfolder/protocol --python_out=./my_folder/data/build ./my_folder/data/my_subfolder/protocol/**/**/*.proto`

It works I do get the same structure into my build folrder.

The problem is, I use a.proto into b.proto and into my b.pb2 the import looks like this:

```
from A.v1 import a_pb2 as alias_name
```

But I'd like it to be:

```
from my_folder.data.build.A.v1 import a_pb2 as alias_name
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you may want to revise how you're invoking `protoc`.

> **NOTE** be careful as there is a difference between Python and other languages in the use of the `package` directive. `package` is not used by Python but it is used by other languages. See [Packages](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#packages)

You'll want to juggle (I'm not entirely sure how you want to remap the folders) `--proto_path` and `--python-out` directories

For example, the following will remove `${PWD}/protocol` from the generated code's output location, using `${PWD}/build` instead while preserve everything below:

```sh
protoc --proto_path=${PWD}/protocol \
--python_out=${PWD}/build \
${PWD}/my_folder/data/my_subfolder/protocol/**/**/*.proto
```

Source:

```
protocol
├── A
│   └── v1
│       └── a.proto
├── B
│   └── v1
│       └── b.proto
└── C
    └── v1
        └── c.proto
```

Output:

```
build
├── A
│   └── v1
│       └── a_pb2.py
├── B
│   └── v1
│       └── b_pb2.py
└── C
    └── v1
        └── c_pb2.py
```

And:

`main.py`:

```py
from build.A.v1 import a_pb2 as some_alias
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the time you took  answering, I will test your method. However, my problem is not about invoking my build protobuf from my python code, this is already working. My problem is about importing built protobuf in other built protobuf so I am not sure this will handle it. I'll keep you informed

Comment: So this gave me the same output as before :/